# Angular not passing body to PUT Method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a PUT call to do an update to a hero resource.

If I hard-code the value as a string and pass it in, things work great. (init and pass in string h as body parameter)

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    , 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  })
};
   /** PUT: update the hero on the server */
  update(hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
    console.log('in  service.update');
    var h: string = '{id:28,name:"g-man",alterEgo:"jeff",superPower:"can fly"}';

    //hero
    return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, h, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))
    );
  }
```

However, if I let Angular pass in hero, the webservice method is called but there is no parameter.

```
 /** PUT: update the hero on the server */
      update(hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
        console.log('in  service.update');
        var h: string = '{id:28,name:"greg",alterEgo:"jeff",superPower:"eggs"}';

        //hero
        return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
          tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
          catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))
        );
      }
```

Here is the webservice method

```
   <HttpPut>
    <Route("")>
    Async Public Function update(<FromBody> mh As mHero) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of CustomJsonStringResult)
        Dim requestBody As String = Await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        Dim ag As New HeroSuperAg
        Dim h As Hero = ag.GetById(mh.id)
        h.name.Value = mh.name
        h.alterEgo.Value = mh.alterEgo
        h.superPower.Value = mh.superPower
        h.Save()
        Return JsonStringResultExtension.JSONString(Me, h.JSON, HttpStatusCode.OK)
    End Function
```

When I stop the code with Angular sending in the parameter, I can inspect hero and get this
[image: inspection of hero variable]

but the method is passed a parameter that is null.

When I pass in the string, a parameter is passed and it is a proper json hero object that I can use.

I have examined every available property of the request object in my service. I do not see the content in either case, either in request.content, or in the header.

I believe this will probably turn out to be some config parameter I need to pass in, but it is escaping me.

This is not a CORS issue.

**Why will Angular not pass a JSON representation of my FORM variables back to the PUT METHOD on my web service**

Here is a picture of the DevTools-Networking tab (Chrome)
[image]
This is after I followed suggestions to pass the content as JSON.stringify(hero)

Comment: I think it's more likely to do with the parsing of json data on your API end

Comment: @david,  interesting. I am not at all convinced Angular is trying to pass json, from inspection, it looks like it is passing KVPs. How could I verify that? When angular passes in hero, the parameter is null.

Comment: try: `this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify(hero), httpOptions).pipe(`

Comment: Check your network tab: for the PUT request, in the Headers tab, at the bottom you've got a **Request Payload** section.Paste a screenshot of that. But it should be a serialised json (but angular handles that, you just need to pass an object)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my content to be JSON.Stringify(hero) as suggested by @CyberCyclist and then @PrishantPimpale. This resolved the issue.

I pasted in the network screenshot as requested. (I was not aware of this debugging resource... thanks for that)

The odd thing is... I wanted to finish out the post and see what it looked like in the error state so I changed my call back to simply passing hero. 
Now I can not get it to fail.

```
this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)

and 

var hjson: string = JSON.stringify(hero)  this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hjson, httpOptions)
```

both work as expected.